# Why can I rename a running executable, but not delete it?

Tags: windows-7, rename

Everything is in the title, but more officially :

Why does Windows let me rename a running executable, but not delete it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There really is no such thing as renaming a file. A file can have more than one name or no name, so it's not the file that you're renaming but the directory entry. Renaming is an operation on the directory entry, which is not affected by the fact that the file is locked for execution.

Comment: Hmm, why then any attempt to rename a regular file that is open for reading or writing fails?

Comment: @Serge: Because the process that opened the file specifically asked for it to fail by setting the appropriate open flags.

Comment: what specific open flags?

Comment: Most likely, setting `dwShareMode` to zero or using the `OF_SHARE_COMPAT` or `OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE` flags.

Answer (score 7):

It does not allow to delete the executable file and DLLs because Windows maps parts of the executable files into memory as part of the process creation, so it need the file during the lifetime of the process.

Unfortunately I have no true reason why it still allows to rename such files. I guess that this is done to enable the update of the dlls and exe files while they are running to minimize the service interruption time.

The linux (unix in general) in contrast allows to delete an executable file while it is running:

```
tmp]$ cp /usr/bin/md5sum .;ll md5*; \
(./md5sum /home/pub/iso/FC5/FC-5-i386-DVD.iso & ); \
rm md5sum ; ll md5*;ps -f
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sergey sergey 37276 Oct 16 02:38 md5sum
ls: cannot access md5*: No such file or directory
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sergey    2423  2422  0 02:32 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
sergey    2533     1  0 02:38 pts/1    00:00:00 ./md5sum /home/pub/iso/FC5/FC-5-
sergey    2536  2423  0 02:38 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -f
```

Comment: Note that e.g. Linux also maps parts of the executable files into memory, but has no problem allowing you to delete a running executable.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Yes, but this I explained here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49299/what-is-linux-doing-differently-that-allows-me-to-remove-replace-files-where-win

Comment: Serge, nice explanation there. :)

Comment: Linux will not allow you to delete a file while it is executing. You can, however, remove directory entries, since those are not executing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz please see the update to my answer. Linux does allow me to unlink any file being executed provided I have enough permissions to delete that file.

Comment: @Serge: As I said, you cannot delete the file. yes, you can unlink the file. The file can only be deleted when its reference count drops to zero which cannot happen while the file is executing. The file just becomes unnamed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In that way I can't delete a file at all. I can only unlink it. Then kernel will do a 'GC' and free the inode.

Comment: @Serge: Correct. The file will be deleted when it has no references. Since the file's reference count cannot drop to zero while it is executing, the file cannot be deleted while it is executing. If unlinked from every directory it was linked to, it will become an unnamed file.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Nevertheless, I got the intention to make a study on what exactly is going on with Win executables when our discussion just began, but now I extended it to see what exactly happens with executables in linux as well. Unfortunately, in former case I can only treat Windows as blackbox and the conclusion will be actually a guess, but for latter case I will see the source :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is because a name is just an attribute of the same binary content of the file, so as long as the data is there, the handle, held by the running process for it won't change.